# SimpleXML Cyrillic Encoding

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, simplexml

This is the type of XML file, which I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductCatalog>
 <ProductType>Дънни платки</ProductType>
 <ProductType>Дънни платки 2</ProductType>     
</ProductCatalog>
```

And when I run the PHP file with the following code:

```
$pFile = new SimpleXMLElement('test.xml', null, true);      
foreach ($pFile->ProductType as $pChild)
{
var_dump($pChild);
}
```

I get the following results:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { [0]=> string(40) "Ð”ÑŠÐ½Ð½Ð° Ð¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‚ÐºÐ° Ð½Ð°ÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð»Ð½Ð°"
```

I have tried different encodings in the XML file but it's not working well with Cyrillic symbols.

Comment: Post a link to your XML file. Also, make sure you output the correct `Content-type` header with the correct charset.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you switch Character encoding (to utf-8) in browser? 
I mean, looks like output issue.